# Caching js files in browser

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm using FastApi (uvicorn) and store js files in static folder,
but when i changed js files browsers show me old version.

```
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
```

I tried clear browser cache (Chrome, edge, firefox) but result is same

Answer (score 0):

We add an unused query string variable to the url for the js file and set it to a value based on time.  For example in an aspx file we use the query string, sn as follows...

```
writer.Write("<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='JavaScript/ClientDiagnostics.js?sn=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + "'></script>");
```